# What is an exclamation point in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

What does an exclamation mark before a function do?

Example:

```
return !loadDynamicBlock();
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A `!` negates an expression.

In your example, if `loadDynamicBlock()` returned true, the function calling it would return false, and vice-versa: `!true == false`

It can also be used to create actual booleans from JavaScript's ideas of [truthy and falsy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/).

```
var a = 5;
!!(a - 5) === false;
!!(a + 5) === true;
```

Answer (score 8):

The `!` in JavaScript inverts a Boolean expression.