# Return !1 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, return

I have just come across a function in JavaScript which has `return !1`.

What does this actually mean? Why would you `return !1` or `return !0`?

Here is the function that I came across:

```
function convertStringToBoolean(a) {
    typeof a == "string" && (a = a.toLowerCase());
    switch (a) {
    case "1":
    case "true":
    case "yes":
    case "y":
    case 1:
    case !0:
        return !0;
    default:
        return !1
    }
}
```

Comment: You should only ever see this in minified code.  If developers are actually coding this way, they should be taken out back and shot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of the broader [What is an exclamation point in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8012003/1529630).

Comment: Have a look at [Is there any point of using “return !0” in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8750104/1048572)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In immediate response to your question:

- `return !1` is equivalent to `return false`
- `return !0` is equivalent to `return true`

In the specification - [11.4.9 Logical NOT Operator](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.4.9) - it states that when you place an exclamation mark `!` in front, the result is evaluated as Boolean and the opposite is returned.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mHDpA/):

```
var a = 1, b = 0;
var c = a || b;
alert("c = " + c + " " + typeof c); // here typeof c will be "number"

a = !0, b = !1;
c = a || b;
alert("c = " + c + " " + typeof c); // here typeof c will be "boolean"
```

I mostly see this in a code passed through Google's [JS optimiser](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home). I think it is mostly done to achieve shortness of the code.

It is often used when a strictly Boolean result is needed - you may see something like `!!(expression)`. Search in jQuery, for example.

Comment: Because the file was compressed I put it through code beautifier (http://jsbeautifier.org/) and it replaced true/false with !0 and !1; I'm not sure why though. I just checked the original but damn it was difficult to find :P Thanks again all!

Comment: Wouldn't that actually create a hit to code performance? A negligible hit perhaps but the same could be said of compressing 4-5 bytes to two to reduce download time of the JS.

Comment: It's completely insignificant performance loss. Check out http://jsperf.com/negated-0-vs-false and you'll see that even the slowest browser can evaluate either one over 170 million times per second.

Comment: But why use !1 instead of 0?
0 Would be even shorter wouldn't it?

Comment: @Mike Yes, it would But then it will be a number, and not a boolean.

Answer (score 11):

This seems to be a particularly silly way of returning `true` or `false`

Comment: 2 bytes vs. 4 (or 5 for false). It takes less bandwidth to download the Javascript! :P

Comment: I hadn't considered that this might have gone through minification.

Answer (score -4):

Here the code it is verifying:

- to return nothing or do nothing on these cases: `"case 1", "case true", "case yes", "case y", "Case 1"`
- and when the case is: `"case !0"` return `"true"`
- when none of the above cases are been satisfied by default, it returns "false"

Comment: This is wrong. This function returns true for all the cases in your first bullet in addition to !0, false otherwise. Not to mention this answer does not address what the user is asking.