# Is there any point of using "return !0" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, minify

If you go to a google result page, and run `rwt.toString()`, you'll see that the return call for this function is:

```
return !0;
```

I can't think of any reason why this wouldn't always be `true`. Is this just a shorthand for `true`, or is there more going on here?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It is always true, but it takes 2 bytes to download (`!0` is 2 characters) instead of 4 bytes to download the boolean value `true`.

Most Javascript minifiers will convert `true` to `!0` and false to `!1`. You can see an example of this by typing `var y = true;` with Simple optimizations on Google's Closure Compiler: http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Comment: however it only takes 1 byte to download 1. return 1; would have worked just as well, no? being non-zero, and we all know you don't test for true, you test for not false.

Comment: This is interesting. Do most javascript implementations optimize !0 and !1 to true and false without calculating?

Comment: @stu `return 1;` returns a `number` type. If someone were to use the return value with the `===` or `!==` operators, they'll get expected results from `!0`, but not from `1`.

Comment: @Kekoa What stu is saying (correct me if I'm wrong, here, stu) is that a minifier will optimize `true` to `!0` and `false` to `!1` to save bandwidth. These expressions get calculated inline by the browser's JavaScript implementation to return boolean values of `true` and `false`, respectively, which is why they pass the strict-equality (`===`) test.