# What does !1 and !0 mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [return !1 in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255653/return-1-in-javascript)

In a JavaScript file I had to read today, there was a line where a variable was declared like a factorial, like this :

```
var myVariable = !1;
```

and then something similar was used as parameter in a function like this :

```
return variable.myFunction(!0);
```

Can anyone explain me what the exclamation mark means in this context and eventually, why this is generally used for (benefits) ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: It's not a factorial, it's a boolean [negation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation) operator.  Turns `true` into `false`, and vice-versa.  Probably turns anything else non-zero into zero?

Comment: That's horrible code.  Does it throw a [`ViolentPsychopathKnowsWhereYouLiveException`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/coding-for-violent-psychopaths.html)?

Comment: I laughed uncontrollably upon seeing the title of this question. I had to click it. SMH to whoever codes like this.

Comment: I guess the reason is that the programmer cared a lot about those few bytes that can be saved this way - but this is not a good practice.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

The ! is the boolean NOT operator.

NOT (!): toggles a statement from true to false or from false to true.

```
!0 = true
!1 = false
```

[This](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/boolean.html) is a brilliant introduction to boolean operators and their use in javascript.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your quick answer ! I will check this question as answered when I can (in 10 minutes).

Comment: Good answer, when you don't know the result on a variable you can always try 'alert(!1)', this will show a pop up with thw word false

Comment: or console.log(variable), so you don't have [object] info

Comment: this a technique to minify values true or false

Comment: why not use `!true` or `!false`, because it is saving download size of the script ?

Comment: @Legends, yes, because JS is transferred over the wire as it is and run at the client.

Comment: @Kronos: Mind blown! It makes sense!

Comment: Additional clarification: why not simply use `0` and `1`? Is it to make sure that after the minification process it is still clear that they are `boolean` and not `int`?

Comment: @don Correct--adding the `!` operator coerces the 0 and 1 from an `int` to a `boolean`.

Comment: @JakeReece thanks for this comment. helps clarify this a lot