# switch(!0) What does it mean

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I saw a piece of code that stuck me as odd.
What does switch(!0) mean in javascript? What are some cases where this technique would be useful to use?

jsTree uses it in a few places but it looks foreign. I'm sure it has a good reason behind it, but can't figure it out.

http://www.jstree.com/

Here is a clip of code:

```
switch(!0) {
    case (!s.data && !s.ajax): throw "Neither data nor ajax settings supplied.";
    case ($.isFunction(s.data)): //...
                                 break;
}
```

Comment: Someone is trying to obfuscate their code I'd say. This is a hacky way to not use `if` and `if else`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does !1 and !0 mean in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550681/what-does-1-and-0-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: Because sensical code is too mainstream. Also, I say we should name these Yoda switches.

Comment: @Mahn HA! I am for the new term. +1 the comment if you like the new term "Yoda switches"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's comparing each of the cases to `boolean true`.

*Elaborating*

```
case (!s.data && !s.ajax)
```

If `!s.data && !s.ajax` evaluates to `true`, then this case will be selected for execution.

`switch(true)` is the same as `switch(!0)`

Comment: Does it just stop on the first true or run all of the true cases?

Comment: It depends if the first case passes or not.

Comment: **!condition** returns false if condition is not false, null, 0 or empty string.

**!!condition** returns true if condition is true
So in this case !0 is true and !1 is false.

Comment: @MMeah: Just the first one that's true.  It's about equivalent to `if`...`else if`, except for the possibility of fall-through in the cases.

Comment: @wanovak If the first case passes, will the second case be evaluated for true?

Comment: No. Unless the `break` statement is omitted. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement

Comment: It won't be evaluated even then.  Absent a `break`, `return`, or `throw`, the program will just fall through to the second case without bothering to check its associated condition.

Comment: If the first case is true and have **break** or **return** or **throw** statement, the thread is go out from the switch body.
In other cases it will go to next case to compare.

Comment: `!0` is 2 characters. `true` is 4. Super optimization! ;-)

Comment: @JohnNelson This is a nice proposal for JS minifiers to convert `true` to `!0` and `false` to `!1` ^_^

Comment: @MMeah the `throw` statement will stop the normal flow of the any code, including the `switch...case` and the exception will bubble up until a `catch` statement handles the thrown exception.

Answer (score 2):

A `switch(!0)` is simply the same as `switch(true)`.

This pattern:

```
switch (true) {
  case (condition): do something; break;
  case (condition): do something; break;
  case (condition): do something; break;
}
```

Works the same as:

```
if (condition) {
  do something;
} else if (condition) {
  do something;
} else if (condition) {
  do something;
}
```

Comment: Except the if statement doesn't allow for fall through if the `break` is removed.

Comment: @MMeah: Yes, that is true. That's doesn't mean that you should use it, though... :)