# javascript = !1 : what does this mean

Tags: javascript, d3.js, underscore.js

I'm new to learning javascript. I've followed a few basic tutorials. I'm trying to understand a script that I found. This script, in several places has something like the following:

```
var USE_CANVAS = !0;
if ("trydom" == window.location.hash || "#trydom" == window.location.hash) USE_CANVAS = !1;
```

I have no idea what this means? When I evaluate for this variable by simply typing it into the console, it returns 'true'.
I can't find any references to this style online.
I should mention that the script is dependent on underscore.js and d3.js, however i personally haven't found anything in these two libraries that looks anything like the above.

Another line that I also cannot explain has to do with the use of "question" and "colon" like so:

```
b.select(".y.axis").call(j)) : "pop" === a ? (c = "rMVMP", j.scale(C).tickV…
```

You can ignore the references to select,call and scale, since these are all d3js functions.
I'm only pasting the second line because I'm not sure whether this is 'javascript' or a completely different language. The file however is named 'chart.js'.

Regards,
Richard.

Comment: I am curious to see what others say. 

0 computes as false
1 as true

And ! is just a negation, so !0 becomes true and !1 becomes false. Now you tell me why... ?

Comment: it means boolean false.  A usual case for this is a minifier will convert false to !1

Comment: It is usually used to minimize the file size. This means faster page loads etc. In a big file, this can make a significant difference in file size.

Comment: [Javascript language reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) and [?:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). Happy reading

Comment: ! is the boolean not operator. this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550681/what-does-1-and-0-mean-in-javascript.  Incidentally ! is the boolean not operator in so many other languages it may be condisered a programming idiom in the context of logical operators.  If ones want to set a variable to true|false it is a better practice to do it explicitly, as in a = true or b = false and not rely on convention that 0 evaluates to false and 1 evaluates to true ina boolean context.

Comment: Regarding !0 and so on, as other pointed out it's a minification construct, and it's a terrible decision to do that in modern code bases. Code should be readable and maintainable. Minification is a build step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `!1` evaluates to `false`. It's not clear why anyone would write code like that.

The `? :` operator stems from the legacy of C. It's the "ternary" operator, and it's sort-of a shorthand (in expression form) for an `if ... else` statement.

Thus

```
test ? whenTrue : whenFalse
```

will evaluate to `whenTrue` when `test` is `true` (or "truthy"), and `whenFalse` when it isn't.

Comment: maybe when someone wants to compare it with another integer representing a boolean value with a type value check too.

Comment: Yes it could be for any reason like that.

Comment: Appears very "golfy", but is strange to see without other minification

Comment: I'll mark this as the right answer because you answered both my questions! You can find where this code came from on the following page : New york times , visualization of the facebook ipo: http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/05/17/business/dealbook/how-the-facebook-offering-compares.html?_r=0

Answer (score 4):

In Javascript, 1 is "truthy", meaning that 1 can represent a boolean true.

That means that 1 can essentially mean true.  Likewise, 0 is falsy, meaning false.

So if something is !1, it's "not true" which means it's false.

```
var USE_CANVAS = !0;
```

is essentially the same as:

```
var USE_CANVAS = true;
```

but takes less space and is usually how minified JS looks.

Comment: @JunedAhsan no, that is not true in JavaScript. `0`, `NaN`, `""`, `false`, `null`, and `undefined` are also interpreted as `false` in a boolean context.

Comment: Good point about the minified JS.  It is helpful to know *why* this code would ever exist.

Comment: this code comes from the nytimes page: http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/05/17/business/dealbook/how-the-facebook-offering-compares.html?_r=0