# what does this.allow = !1 and this.allow = !0 mean?

Tags: jquery, object, canvas

I tried to understand some code.
It begin like this:

```
function Drawing(varCanvas, varSize, varPrice) {
    var c = this;
    this.allow = !1;
    this.size = varSize;
    this.$canvas = varCanvas;
(.....)
    this.allow = !0;
```

I don't understand why the developer wrote "this.allow = !1;"
I never seen this writing before.

Comment: !1 means boolean `false` and !0 means boolean `true` value.

Comment: That's shortcut way to write booleans, killing readability...

Comment: @SouvirLy 1 and 0 aren't booleans

Comment: Ok I get it,
Thanks for your answers.
How do you write it to be more understandable ?

Comment: Just write `this.allow = false;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does !1 and !0 mean in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550681/what-does-1-and-0-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest I have never seen this myself, but its effect is:

`!1` is the same as `false`

`!0` is the same as `true`

so instead of `this.allow = !1;` you could write `this.allow = false;`

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: It is usually used by JS minifiers to minify JS code size. A sane developer shouldn't write such code manually.