# Clarification about variable assignment? "var x = !0"

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

I am going through a javascript library and I would like to know why you would define a variable like this...

```
points: {
   show: !0
},
```

Why would you do `show: !0` instead of just `show: 1`?

I don't think this question is necessarily specific to javascript but I tagged the question with it anyway just in case it was actually something language specific.

Comment: possible duplicate of [return !1 in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255653/return-1-in-javascript)

Comment: I tried to search for answers to this before posting but google doesn't handle punctuation well.  Thanks for the link - I think it answers every follow up question I have, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Javascript, `!` with any falsy value returns `true`.
This is a common trick used by minifiers to save two character.s

Answer (score 1):

That evaluates to true. Not quite sure why it's being used as there's no context so that's all I can tell you.