# Operator !! arrow functions

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6

What means !! in arrow function bellow ?
Differences betwen ! and !! ?

```
 v => !!v || 'Required',
```

I'm using this function in vuetify rules props

```
nameRules: [
           v => !!v || 'Required',
       .....
```

Comment: Also, that is short version of
`
nameRules: [
  function(v) {
    return !!v || "Required";
  }
];
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In vue.js (and javascript in general), one exclamation point [negates an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012003/what-is-an-exclamation-point-in-javascript?answertab=votes#tab-top), two exclamation points [ensures a boolean type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284664/double-exclamation-points?answertab=votes#tab-top)