# Why required check not working after removing element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

Could you please tell why my required check is not working in autocomplete .I am using `material UI` with react hook form.
Step to reproduce

- Click `Submit` button  it show field is required.
- then select any element from list.
- remove the selected element  Then click again submit button.It should
  show “required” field check.but it is not showing anything why ??

Here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-autocomplete-with-react-hook-form-0wvpq

```
 <Controller
      as={
        <Autocomplete
          id="country-select-demo"
          multiple
          style={{ width: 300 }}
          options={countries}
          classes={{
            option: classes.option
          }}
          autoHighlight
          getOptionLabel={option => option.label}
          renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
            <React.Fragment>
              <Checkbox
                icon={icon}
                checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
                style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
                checked={selected}
              />
              {option.label} ({option.code}) +{option.phone}
            </React.Fragment>
          )}
          renderInput={params => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              label="Choose a country"
              variant="outlined"
              fullWidth
              name="country"
              inputRef={register({ required: true })}
              //  required
              error={errors["country"] ? true : false}
              inputProps={{
                ...params.inputProps,
                autoComplete: "disabled" // disable autocomplete and autofill
              }}
            />
          )}
        />
      }
      onChange={([event, data]) => {
        return data;
      }}
      name="country"
      control={control}
    />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the form loads initially, the value of your form is an empty object -

```
{}
```

When you select a country (say, 'Andorra') the value of your form becomes:

```
{"country":[{"code":"AD","label":"Andorra","phone":"376"}]}
```

And then when you deselect the country, the value of your form becomes:

```
{"country":[]}
```

An empty array technically meets the "required" criteria (it's not null, after all) so your required handler doesn't fire.

You can verify this is happening by showing the value of the form in your `App` class -

```
const { control, handleSubmit, errors, register, getValues } = useForm({});
return (
  <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit(data => console.log(data))}>
    <Countries control={control} errors={errors} register={register} />
    <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit">
      Submit
    </Button>
    <code>{JSON.stringify(getValues())}</code>
  </form>
);
```

The simple fix is to NOT return an empty array as a value from your control - update your `onChange` handler as follows -

```
onChange={([event, data]) => {
    return data && data.length ? data : undefined;
}}
```

Comment: Thanks working fine ..https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-autocomplete-with-react-hook-form-0wvpq

Comment: but i have one issue cooming https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-autocomplete-with-react-hook-form-0wvpq

Comment: `Material-UI: A component is changing an uncontrolled useAutocomplete to be controlled.`

Comment: whenever i select it show me this error https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-autocomplete-with-react-hook-form-0wvpq

Comment: I alreay defined `initial state` or defalut state

Comment: That's because of this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53072573/127497 - you'd have to change the defaultValues to `country: []` - but then it breaks your `required` validator. I think you'll probably have to use a custom validation function here instead.

Comment: do you have any how ??

Comment: do you know any custom validator function know

Comment: it would be great if you help me in codesandbox ..my latest sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-autocomplete-with-react-hook-form-0wvpq

Comment: I've never used Material or React Hook Form but it seems pretty straight-forward? https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-autocomplete-with-react-hook-form-hyqwv

Comment: after `empty array` it works but stop `required validation`

Comment: Did you try the code sandbox I sent through? I removed the `required` validator and added in a custom validator instead - the form is invalid if there are no countries selected, which I figured was the main objective here?

Comment: where you sent ??

Comment: can you share the link

Comment: It's in my comment above - codesandbox.io/s/mui-autocomplete-with-react-hook-form-hyqwv